# Is there a way for my useEffect hook to rerender right away when my state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a state of todos that is an empty array to begin with. And I add an object to the todos state with a property of completed set to false initially for all added todos.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

const [todoForm, setTodoForm] = useState({
    id: null,
    task: '',
    completed: false,
    time: '',
  });
```

And here is the useEffect hook that I use to update my todos

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const sortedArray = todos.sort((a, b) => b.completed - a.completed);
    setTodos(sortedArray);
  }, [todos, todos.completed]);
```

```
const toggleComplete = (id) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed,
          };
        }
        return todo;
      })
    );
  };
```

The problem is that when I first click on a todo and it is completed it does not go all the way to the top. Here is a picture :
[image]

It does not rerender until I click another one like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Sort is an in-place sort, which means it mutates the state object.

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
> the sorted array.

## Solution

Sort the array when toggling the "completed" status in the handler. Copy the `todos` array first, so there is a new state array reference, then sort.

```
const toggleComplete = (id) => {
  setTodos((todos) =>
    todos
      .map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed
          };
        }
        return todo;
      })
      .sort((a, b) => b.completed - a.completed)
  );
};
```

Comment: I have not tested this, but at first glance would this create a loop? setTodos updates todos to a new reference which in turn fires the useEffect again. Your answer is correct, but I am assuming that the array sort is not going to be the full issue.

Comment: hmm, my app freeze when I click one of the check boxes. I do have a function that toggles the check box. Maybe that causes it to freeze

Comment: or it creates a loop as @JacobSmit says

Comment: @EirikVattøy Shoot, totally correct. I guess you should do the sort when updating the state, i.e. when toggling a todo to "completed" and vice-versa. Can you update your question with the toggle handler?

Comment: @DrewReese Done!

Comment: @EirikVattøy Updated answer. So sorry for the first version.